# ArcPy mp Layout text

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to change the text in my map layout for numerous map series. I wanted to do this via Python but am running into an issue with ArcGIS Pro's new format. I used the code from other sites but for some reason I get the error

```
title.text = "A"
'list' object has not attribute text
```

This is my code

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'J:\238\07_MS4\GIS\NorthHaven_MS4_GIS\NorthHaven_MS4_GIS1.aprx')
layout = aprx.listLayouts('Layout1')[0]
title = layout.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT', 'Title')
title.text = "A"
aprx.save()
del aprx
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change:

```
title = layout.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT', 'Title')
```

to:

```
title = layout.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT', 'Title')[0]
```

That way you create a single TextElement object (the first from a list) instead of a list of TextElement objects.

A TextElement object has a text property while a list object does not.